# Understanding architecture results from lipo tool

Tags: ios, xcode, lipo

I built an Xcode project for armv7, armv7s arm64. I ran `lipo -info` on the resulting .a file:

> Architectures in the fat file: Release-iphoneos/libhlsl2glsl.a are:
>   armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) (cputype (16777228) cpusubtype
>   (0))

What is this telling me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's display `cputype` and `cpusubtype` that you gets by using the functions `sysctl`or `syctlbyname`. See mach/machine.h for defined values :

for `cputype`, 12 is for ARM CPU

```
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM ((cpu_type_t) 12)
```

16777228 (aka 0x100000C) is for ARM64 CPU : `CPU_TYPE_ARM | CPU_ARCH_ABI64`

```
#define CPU_ARCH_ABI64  0x01000000 /* 64 bit ABI */
```

for `cpusubtype` :

```
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7S ((cpu_subtype_t) 11) /* Swift */

#define CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_ALL ((cpu_subtype_t) 0)
```

Comment: How come it isn't displaying the proper name then - I see some people report this would just write "armv7 armv7s arm64"? I installed the latest XCode command-line tools already...

Comment: @John Do you have multiple versions of Xcode installed ? It's seems that the command line tools are not properly installed… Try using `xcrun -r lipo -info /path/to/libhlsl2glsl.a`