# Xcode 5.1 and compiling error for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paypal, x86-64

Yesterday I had a project working without problem with Xcode 5. Today, after the update to Xcode 5.1 i have 6 errors and the project is not compiling.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPal", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SUAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SUTViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalAdvancedPayment", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SUTViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SUTViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SUTViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SUTViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The project includes the **PayPal library** and it is linked properly into the code. It is there, I can see the library, so it is not a missing library.

Running the code in the 6.1 Simulator compiles without problem.

Can be a problem with the new Xcode 5.1 feature "*Updates the iOS standard architecture setting to include 64-bit.*" ?

Maybe I should change the standard Architecture? Or something related to the PayPal library?

Someone know how to solve that?

Comment: "after the update to Xcode 7.1"  really?

Comment: Removing arm64 from Target / Build Settings / Architectures / Valid Architectures allows me to compile the project. But that means I'm not compiling for 64-bits?

Comment: i think the library you are using, does not support arm64. check if its update is available.

Comment: 5.1 sorry, it was a mixing between iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1 :)

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/47) , it report the same problem for paypal library.

Comment: Yep, my PayPal lib is to old. :(

Comment: Version 2.0.1 Available: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases compatible with 64-bit since 1.4.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i think the  paypal library you are using, does not support arm64.

check this [PayPal-iOS-SDK issue-47](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/47) for the updated paypal library.

Edit :- [update link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases) for paypal library (with arm64 support)

Comment: Version 2.0.1 Available: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases compatible with 64-bit since 1.4.1

Answer (score 12):

Select app target's Build Settings, select Architectures, click on Other... and  **remove $(ARCHS_STANDARD)** and **add $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)**

Below is image for same[image: In app Target's -> Build Settings -> Architectures]

Its fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags Add -ObjC -l"PayPalMobile" -l"Pods-PayPal-iOS-SDK" -l"c++" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "SystemConfiguration"

Answer (score 0):

If you just miss x86_64 architecture (but you have arm64) and it's not possible to get library that includes x86_64 architecture, do the following:

[image: adding different architectures for different SDKs]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikita's answer, you could change the parameter from "i386" to `x86_64` to compile the library matching `x86_64` architecture. Then the compiling errors will go away.