# Architecture linking error after Xcode 5.1 upgrade

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7.1, xcode5.1

**I am having these errors:**
libGPUImage.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s),
libPods.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s)
 and more...

**These are my project settings:**
Architectures:armv7,armv7s,arm64
Build Active Architectures Only:NO
Valid Architectures;armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386

I didn't change anything except for downloading latest Xcode 5.1 with the iOS 7.1 SDK. This project worked fine with Xcode 5.0 and iOS 7.0 SDK. What could be the problem?

Comment: Here is an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341511/how-to-link-with-framework-without-arm64-support-in-xcode-5-1

Comment: this can be possible fix
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22682667/1000906

Answer (score 4):

Got to Build Settings -> Architectures

You probably have Standard Architectures set, right?

As of Xcode 5.1 Standard Architectures includes arm64, which you are not ready to support.

Select Other..

doubleclick $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and change it to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

Note: This is a temporary fix. You are probably using some static library that didn't come with a 64-bit slice. See if there is one available and then switch Architecture back to Standard Architectures.

Answer (score 3):

I had a bunch of similar issues upgrading to Xcode 5.1. I resolved them by first updating CocoaPods:

`gem update cocoapods`

Then updating the pods in my project:

`pod update`

In my case, there was some corrupted stuff in my `~/.cocoapods` directory which was causing `pod` to throw errors. Deleting everything in `~/.cocoapods` then running `pod update` again got things working again.

Comment: did u manually remove arm64 from Architectures? Cocopods does not seem to pull 64bit versions

Comment: No, all I had to do was update both CocoaPods itself, and the pods that I was using, and the architecture build errors went away.

Answer (score 2):

We had this same thing happen to us, the problem is "Standard Architectures" under "Architectures" used to be `armv7, armv7s`, in Xcode 5.1 Apple changed "Standard Architectures" to be `armv7, armv7s, arm64` so now you have to manually enter your own architectures instead of picking "Standard".

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer for the OP. The standard architectures for 5.1 now include `arm64`, and they did not before. Either OP can remove `arm64` from the architectures and add the two prior 32-bit versions, or *preferably* find 64-bit versions of the linked libraries.

Comment: changed settings to remove arm64 from architectures but it did nothing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3dcod63hxmrgn4/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-11%20at%205.59.40%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Open in some text editor (for instance SublimeText) your `./Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file. Usually with the following command in the terminal (keep in mine you have to be in your project directory) `st ./Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and find and replace `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES` with `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO`. Also you can do the same with your `{YOUR_PROJECT}.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. And last Clean and Run from the Xcode!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was fixed by changing `_view` to `self.view`.