# How to link with framework without arm64 support in Xcode 5.1?

Tags: ios7.1, xcode5.1

After upgraded a project on Xcode 5.1, Product > Build gives the following warning and error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file Dropbox/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox, missing
>   required architecture arm64 in file Dropbox.framework/Dropbox (3
>   slices)
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DBPath",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DropboxViewController.o

It seems like the Dropbox.framework does not support arm64 yet.

What are the Xcode settings to remove arm64 support from the project to have a clean build?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Change:

- **Architectures**: `Standard`
- **Valid Architectures**: `arm64 armv7 armv7s`

To:

- **Architectures**: `armv7 armv7s`
- **Valid Architectures**: `armv7 armv7s`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `armv64` in

> Project > Build Settings > Architectures> Valid Architectures

( i.e. leave only `armv7` and `armv7s` )

Also, set `Build Active Architectures Only` to `NO`.