# Unity 4.3.4f1 and Xcode 5.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode5.1

Xcode 5.1 just released. I installed the latest version of Xcode 5.1 as well as Unity 4.3.4f1.

Before updating Xcode to version 5.1, Unity project builds without problem. In the mentioned version, the following errors appeared when I hit "Build and Run" in Unity3D:

In Unity:

> UnityException: Launching iOS project via Xcode4 failed. Check editor log for details.

Well, I'm not using Xcode4. Xcode fails to load. Then I open the Xcode project manually. When I try to compile the Xcode project, the following compile errors occurs:

> Dsymutil Error: error: invalid abbreviation code [114] for DIE at 0x00005e22 in

and

> Dsymutil Error: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

What do they mean? How can I resolve it?

Note: the App build is successful on device.

The device is iOS 6.1.4, iPhone 5.

Comment: Thanks for sharing mate, I was going to update XCode but I will wait a bit, I am searching for more info, I will let you know if I find something worth sharing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you change the "Debug Information Format" to DWARF, the error will go away.

DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf

[image]

I got this answer from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/233591-Error-in-lastest-XCode)

Comment: I can't find this "Debug Information Format". Where exactly is it ?

Comment: Go to your build settings and then search for that key

Comment: But it's not an option. You will not be able to read crash reports without dSYM.

Answer (score 4):

You can get Build and Run working again in Unity w/ the latest Xcode by following the steps in this thread
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/234557-nityException-Launching-iOS-project-via-Xcode4-failed

Comment: We're talking about Xcode 5, not Xcode 4; and I'm using the latest Xcode at this moment.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! (Unity 4.3.4, Xcode 5.1.1, iOS 7.1)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a definitive answer but in the meantime I did this on my project and I manage to compile and make it work on an iPad with the latest iOS 7.1.
[image]

I was able to compile with no errors but warnings by removing armv7 and arm64 from the architectures.

Some references here: [Architecture linking error after Xcode 5.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339656/architecture-linking-error-after-xcode-5-1-upgrade)

Comment: That's definitely a useful hint on the error. Hope Unity will have updates for this.

Comment: What is a bit strange is that in the unity forums people is not complaining, have you already reported the problem yo unity?

Comment: Seems I have insufficient rights to post in Issue Tracker :(

Answer (score 2):

I currently have the latest `Unity 4.3.4f1` and `Xcode 5.1/iOS 7.1` sdk installed and using `Build and Run` in Unity to automatically get a build on an iOS device also fails for me.

Just do:

> File > Build Settings... > Build

in Unity, manually open the project in Xcode, and build/run it normally from Xcode - it still compiles and runs fine on a connected device.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I do (mentioned in question). But the error still exists, if you look into the Problem tab in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix Xcode 5.1 support by manually editing Unity Xcode plugin metadata.

1. Find following file in Unity installation:

**Unity.app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/iPhonePlayer/Unity4XC.xcplugin/Contents/Info.plist**

1. Open it with XCode and locate following lines here:

   DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2. Insert following item just before closing

   A2E4D43F-41F4-4FB9-BB94-7177011C9AED
3. Restart Xcode.

Comment: How do you get these values ?

Comment: By this command  "defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID" I got exactly the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Unity to 4.5 (using XCode 5.1.1) solved the problem for me.