# Error arm64 Xcode and Parse

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi friend have this error:

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInstallation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseExampleAppDelegate.o

 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFPush", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseExampleAppDelegate.o

 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ParseExampleViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in Buongiorno.o
      objc-class-ref in ParseImageViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in Compleanno.o
      objc-class-ref in Buonanotte.o

 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o

 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseExampleAppDelegate.o

     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseExampleViewController, _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseExampleCell , _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseImageViewController , _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseExampleAppDelegate )

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331908/xcode-5-1-missing-required-architecture-arm64