# Xcode 5 app archiving wont work

Tags: ios, xcode

Please help me out, I get the following warning and 12 errors!

I already tried changing the build active architecture only to no.

l

```
d: warning: ignoring file /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Move4u-ewfgdiwoasxtpydtflwbbzybqgqp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Move4u/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/kevin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Move4u-ewfgdiwoasxtpydtflwbbzybqgqp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Move4u/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DatePicker in DatePicker.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DatePicker in DatePicker.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DatePicker.o
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331908/xcode-5-1-missing-required-architecture-arm64).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove arm64 from the valid architectures.

Comment: Didn't work, the fix was setting the architecture to: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)