# Error : Undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am getting below error. It was working fine and I don't have any idea about what caused this issue.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/akashpatel/Developer/iOS_development/FantasyCricket/Fantasy_cricket/Library/JMC/JMCClasses/Libraries/CrashReporter.framework/CrashReporter, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/akashpatel/Developer/iOS_development/FantasyCricket/Fantasy_cricket/Library/JMC/JMCClasses/Libraries/CrashReporter.framework/CrashReporter (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReport", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CrashReporter.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReporter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CrashReporter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried removing and adding `CrashReporter` from and to project.

Comment: Seems like your CrashReporter not support arm64 architecture. 
Try to remove arm64 from "Valid Architectures" list in "Build Settings" tab.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331908/xcode-5-1-missing-required-architecture-arm64

Answer (score 0):

Select your project, go to `Build Settings` and have a look at the `Architectures`. You should delete **arm64** from the `Architectures` and also from `Valid Architectures` and Build the app again.