# Missing required architecture arm64

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I have been running my app fine on a ipad mini throughout development but tried testing it on an iPad air 2 today and it wont run. I get the following warning

`ignoring file /ProjectFolder/SwiftEverlive/EverliveSDK.framework/EverliveSDK, missing required architecture arm64 in file /ProjectFolder/SwiftEverlive/EverliveSDK.framework/EverliveSDK (2 slices)`

**my architectures settigs in my project**
[image]

It also doesn’t run on the simulator. I also tried opening the project in the Swift everlive folder but that won't open. It says its missing the `project.pbxproj` file

To be honest did not understand the other answers for similar questions here. Sorry very new to iOS dev.

**Edit**
The problem seems to be in the settings of the Telerik Everlive Framework and how that was complied is sthere any way i cam fixthis as i dont have time for them to suggest a solution.

Comment: Here is the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22370729/3515115
Hope this helps

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya Thanks i have looked at this post but i dont understand how to implement the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing this means that you are trying to use a framework, namely EverliveSDK, that has not been compiled for a the new 64 bit arm processor in the iPad Air 2. Framework files come with a lot of precompiled code - sometimes intended to be proprietary - and if it hasn't been compiled for your target architecture then you cannot use that framework on that architecture.

Comment: So would this mean if i 'cannot use that framework on that architecture' i cant use it on the newer devices? or is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure which devices use 64 bit arm processors. I know that they're newer but I don't know if all the newer devices use them. But yes it sounds like this framework cannot run 64 bit arms.

Comment: recompiling the lib for your arch would solve it; however the possibility of recompiling for the said arch is ambiguous, or might not be possible at all.

Comment: @Shark thanks for your input. how would i try this? as i said in the post i cant open the project file that was included in the framework

Answer (score 1):

The devices that use the arm64 architecture are iPhone 5s and newer. The simulator uses the architectures i386 or i86. If you have the framework available to you (it should look like a little white lego) it should contain a text file of the same name. This text file will appear to contain a bunch of gibberish, however, if you run the command 'lipo -info' on this file in the terminal, if will tell you which architectures the framework contains. I suspect you will be missing arm64, in which case you can't use the framework on the aforementioned devices.

Answer (score 0):

The follow solved the problem:

```
 1. You can try to add arm64 to the Build Settings -> Architectures ->
    Excluded Architectures for Any iOS Simulator SDK. It helps many of
    devs, but for me it didn't work.
 2. You can Clean Build Folder (⇧ + ⌘ +
    K), clean DerivedData directory, CocoaPods caches, and restart
    macOS, Xcode and Simulator. This solution works for me.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
Remove all valid architecture. It just only set **armv7** and **armv7s**.
Just change **Build Settings -> Architectures -> Build Active Architecture Only -> Debug -> NO**.

Comment: Sorry This does help.

Comment: this does not help