# "Semantic error: Redefinition of '__ccContentScaleFactor' with a different type" in Cocos2D v2

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have developed a new game and it is running perfectly fine on my real ios devices and even on simulators but when i decided to submit it to AppStore it is giving error on this line.

```
extern CGFloat  __ccContentScaleFactor;
```

and error is

```
cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/CCDirectorIOS.h:102:16: Redefinition of '__ccContentScaleFactor' with a different type: 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float'
```

can anyone please help me with this issue i just update xcode to 5.1. thanks

Comment: Here is how to remove arm64 from your project's build settings - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1

Comment: Note that cocos2d 2.2 was released a few days ago with 64-bit support. Source: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-classic . Announcement: http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/cocos2d-iphone-2-1-64-bit-fix/15919

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## **Important Update:**

---

### [Cocos2D v2.2 with 64-Bit fixes has been released.](http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/cocos2d-iphone-2-1-64-bit-fix/15919)

I strongly suggest every cocos2d v2.x developer to upgrade to this version rather than applying the quick fix below. There are many 64-Bit compatibility issues lurking in cocos2d v2.0 and v2.1, which may rear their ugly head in weird bugs, visual glitches or more compile errors - depending on the app.

Beginning in February 2015 Apple will only accept new apps and app upgrades which include 64-Bit binaries. So it's highly recommended to get your code and cocos2d to a proper working state on 64-bit devices.

---

### *Quick & dirty fix only for this particular issue:*

Edit the line the compiler complains about, change `CGFloat` to `float` so that it reads:

```
extern float  __ccContentScaleFactor;
```

However this indicates that xcode is building the arm64 slice. For cocos2d-iphone v2.x it is best to disable/remove arm64 from supported architectures because **Cocos2D v2.1 and earlier are not fully compatible with 64bit devices!**

There can be weird bugs and side-effects when running a Cocos2D v2.1 or earlier app compiled as 64-bit code and running on a 64-Bit device (iPhone 5S and newer). These issues may not occur on the iOS Simulator.

Comment: had to add in CCDirectorIOS.m: float  __ccContentScaleFactor = 1;

Comment: This is an easy fix, but does anyone know how to implement this fix if it's tripping you up in Cocoapods?  (I'm trying to create a cocoapod library with a dependency on cocos2d and it won't push because of this error)

Comment: hello @LearnCocos2D. as from February arm64 will be compulsory. what is the solution for this problem now.this will not work anymore.thanks

Comment: Edited answer, the (only) solution is to upgrade to cocos2d v2.2.

Comment: I'm pulling in Cocos2D using Cocoapods. Cocoapods is saying that v2.1 is the most recent version of Cocos2D. How can I get v2.2 through Cocoapods? Am I stuck?

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut you can get Cocos2D 2.2 from the Github page https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-classic/tree/v2.2 or the Cocos2D website http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/download.  Not sure how it all works with Cocoapods but at least those are ways you can get v2.2 code

Answer (score 2):

As now developers are finding new solution for this problem . because apple says ARM64 will be compulsory from February, 2015 . so you can fix this by just changing:

```
   CGFloat
```

to

```
    float
```

where every you get this problem in coco2d project.
thanks