# Xcode Cocos2D - warning all apps should include an armv7 architecture

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

My project started doing something odd.  I can build and test OK, but when I archive I get:

```
Warning all apps should include an armv7 architecture
```

In Target build settings I have Architectures set as $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and Base SDK as Latest iOS with Valid Architectures set as arm64 armv7 armv7s

I googled this and found several solutions saying to go to Target>Build Settings>Build Active Architecture Only and set that to NO.

Doing that, the project will no longer build and I get:

```
CCDirectorIOS.h    Semantic issue   
Redefinition of '__ccContentScaleFactor' with a different type: 
'CGFloat' (aka double) vs 'float'
```

I'm quite a way through with this project and this is the first time I've had this problem.  I've tried restoring from an earlier good backup and I get the same problem so presumably this has been caused by an Xcode update, and not by my own code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocos2d-iphone semantic error: Redefinition of '__ccContentScaleFactor' with a different type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335655/ios-game-giving-error-when-creating-archive-for-appstore)

Comment: Be sure to remove the arm64 slice if you're using v2.x of cocos2d-iphone as it is not compatible with 64bit builds.

Comment: Thanks, a combination of that and changing the supported architecture to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) has solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Solution is simple, Change CGFloat to float

```
 extern float  __ccContentScaleFactor;
```

Here is [discussion](http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/cocos2d-iphone-2-1-64-bit-fix/15919/7) about Cocos2d 64 bit support

Comment: Thanks.  I already tried this solution which I found elsewhere with no luck, but when I combined it with removing arm64 that did the trick!