# App will no longer compile

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

So my app will no longer compile now that I updated to iOS 7.1, here's the error

```
CCDirectorIOS.h:109:16: Redefinition of '__ccContentScaleFactor' with a different type: 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float'
```

With cocos2d v2.

I tried updating to cocos2dv3 but I have to change 90% of my code it seems. Is there a way I can somehow update cocos2d to compile with iOS 7.1?

Comment: Try removing arm64 from your build architectures or changing one of the definitions of ccContentScaleFactor so that both are float, or both are CGFloat

Comment: once I removed arm64 it compiled fine, but now app crashes when I load a scene. Gotta love iOS updates.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335655/cocos2d-iphone-semantic-error-redefinition-of-cccontentscalefactor-with-a-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your app is based on some sample apps/code that's distributed with Cocos2D - and the samples aren't up to date for iOS7.

You can work to bring them up to date if you want - not sure how much work that's going to be in total. The specific incompatibility you're looking at is just an extern - go in CCDirectorIOS.h and make it much the new signature (I'm guessing it's a float now).

See this commit for a fix: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/001c611b4265a379ca05cf3c90e07dd0d98651a8

Comment: Also had to remove arm64 from my build architectures.