# Missing 64-bit support in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode6, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

So I set my project to:

- Standard Architectures
- Base SDK 8.0
- Valid Architectues - "armv7 armv7s arm64"
- Build Valid Architectures - "Debug - Yes, Release - No"
- Deployment Target to "iOS 7"
- Currently running xCode 6

Yet I am getting this one error message:

> extern CGFloat __ccContentScaleFactor; *(**Redefinition of '__ccContentScaleFactor' with a different type: 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float'**)*

What should I do to fix this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `__ccContentScaleFactor` defined? Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335655/semantic-error-redefinition-of-cccontentscalefactor-with-a-different-type) by any chance?

Comment: It is located in CCDirectorIOS.h.  The quick fix in that post says to change it to 32 bit but I'm trying to make it so it is compatible with 64-bit.  Is there any workaround with this?

Comment: Have you tried updating Cocos2D?

Comment: How would I go about updating?  Sorry for being such a novice

Comment: I've never worked with Cocos2D myself, though your problem seems like something to me, that has already been fixed in newer versions of the framework. What version are currently using and how did you install Cocos2D? You should probably be able to update it the same way, you have installed it in the first place.