# ios 7 xcode 5.01 app doesnt start after validate components

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, xcode5.0.1

I got a warning in Xcode 5.01 indicating that I needed to validate components. I clicked the button to do the validation and since then my app doesn't actually start on the simulator. I know I'm being vague but I do recall a message about validating components.

Xcode says the app is running on the simulator but I don't see my app ever appearing on the simulator any more.

I've cleaned the app and reset the simulator. I put a breakpoint in main.m but it never executes. And the breakpoint buttons to step into, over, etc are not highlighted so it is as if it has not reached the main.m breakpoint.

I also don't see any  messages in the debug console.

Any idea what happened and what I can do?

Thanks

Comment: I see now that the warning was Validate Project Settings Update to recommended settings.

Comment: I'm hoping that this article will take care of my problem: http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that the app had added arm64 when it did a Validate Project. However, I had an API, that I think only supports 32-bit. So I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372264/ios-7-1-gives-error-after-updating-to-xcode-5-1) which resolved the problem.