# build error on iOS 7.1 - Zxing

Tags: ios, zxing, ios7.1, xcode5.1

Updated to **XCODE 5.1/IOS 7.1** and tried to build my project which included [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library.
Getting the following error:

```
/Zxing/cpp/core/src/zxing/ChecksumException.h:3:9: '__CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H__' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro
```

Error is occurring for the following code,

```
#ifndef __CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H__   //this line causes the error.
#define __NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION_H__

.....

.....

#endif // __CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H__
```

**Everything was perfect before the xcode 5.1 update.**

I suspect recent migration of **IOS 7.1** to support **64-bit architecture** causes this error but i'm not sure.

I tried to remove 64-bit support from the Zxing library using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1?rq=1) but still it's not working.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question description is updated now. I think we should not close this question as many people are facing the same issue. Please let me know if more information is required to uplift the ban. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Looks like there are some underground compiler settings changes in XCode 5.1.

So to fix this issue you need add -w flag to ZXingWidget Other Warning Flags.
This flag completely disable all compiler warnings.

1. Select ZXingWidget framework.
2. Select ZXingWidget target in ZXingWidget framework.
3. Press Build setting tab and type "other wa" in search.
4. Add -w parameter flag to Other Warning Flags.

Here is a screen with steps how to add this flag:
[image: How to add -w other warning flag screen]