# Architecture Build Settings Won't Change in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I strongly feel like I'm missing something simple but I can't seem to find what the issue is. I am working on this iOS tutorial and recently updated xcode to 5.1. After opening xcode I noticed that I was receiving warnings that I wasn't getting before.

After some research I've found that it's caused from the fact that xcode changed some of my default build settings... namely my Architecture setting in build settings.

I am now trying to change that setting to not include arm64 (and only armv7 and armv7s) but for some reason I cannot change it. The option is not click-editable nor is there any other options in the drop down menu... any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **Architectures** value will currently be set to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`, which as of Xcode 5.1 includes arm64. You should certainly be able to edit the value - just double click it like you would any other value in the Build Settings.

To remove arm64, you can change the value to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`, which just includes armv7 and armv7s. You may also need to edit **Valid Architectures** to remove arm64 from there.

However, if possible, you should try and ensure you support arm64 within your app.

Comment: For some odd reason double clicking just opens a drop down menu (as shown in the second screenshot). The only area thats double click editable is the Valid Architectures section

Comment: Have you uploaded the same screenshot twice? They both appear the same to me?

Comment: Ah... my mistake. I've uploaded the second screenshot. Thats what happens when I try to double click edit it

Comment: Okay, then click 'Other' in the dropdown... you should be able to type in the new value there.

Comment: That works... the detailed answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1?rq=1

Comment: I have one question: Why or When "You may also need to edit Valid Architectures"?? I've set $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) as Architectures and I've set arm64, armv7s, armv7 in valid architectures. I'm able to run with iphone 64bit simulator. But I don't try the real device.

Answer (score 0):

First you might click on the "Combined" menu item, makes things a lot easier. Now you have "Levels" selected, which shows you (left to right):

- default values by Xcode
- values defined for the project
- values defined for this target
- currently active value

Second, I got in all popup menus "Other..." which allows me to write there anything. If you want to force app 32-bit, try this string:

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
```