# Forcing iPhone 6/6 Plus Simulator in 32-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am looking for a way to force iPhone 6/6 Plus Simulator to run in 32-bit mode.

The reason being is I have a static library in my project that wasn't built to support x86_64, but I need a method to test my app on the iPhone 6/6 Plus resolution.

And I don't want to lose the 64-bit support altogether. (That is, the app already runs in 64-bit on real devices with arm64, and I want to leave it as-is.)

Previously Xcode had separate simulators for each screen size, 32/64-bit so I could just use the 32-bit 4-inch/3.5-inch simulator, but now the simulators seem to be device-specific.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a viable solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025652/testing-32-bit-ios-app-on-iphone-5s-or-64-bit-simulator

Comment: @Pruthvikar I'm afraid that changing the build settings would make Xcode compile only for 32-bit, and that is not what I am looking for. I could always toggle between architecture every time I would like to use a simulator instead of a real device, but that would be too much cumbersome. Instead I'd like the simulator to prefer 32-bit binary instead of 64-bit, much like those regular 3.5-inch/4-inch simulators we had in older versions of Xcode. (i.e., iPhone Retina (4.7-inch or 5.5-inch))

Comment: I wonder how to cope with the fact that 64bit is now requirement (applying from February 2015). E.g. a sort of preference of 32bit launch of the app inside Info.plist would be nice to deal with such things like missing 64bit prebuilt libraries.

Comment: @SunwooPark Since my library only supports for x86_64. Can you help how can I force my app to use only 64-bit Simulators?