# How to Fix ChartBoost SDK 4.4 Error "libChartboost.a, missing required architecture x86_64"

Tags: xcode, sdk, integration, chartboost

After successfully integrating Chartboost SDK 4.2 into my Appstore published Apps, I'm encountering errors when upgrading to SDK 4.4 in Xcode: "libChartboost.a, missing required architecture x86_64". Currently the documentation at https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios is not yet updated for SDK 4.4.

While playing around with architectures (I'm not willing to remove "arm64" from my valid architectures as "arm64" worked fine with SDK 4.2, and I'd prefer to support 64-bit systems) am I left to conclude that SDK 4.4 does not support "arm64"?

Have tried re-installing SDK 4.4, and have cleaned build folder a few times. What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

x86_64 is the architecture required for your Simulator not your devices, therefore, removing it doesn't affect your final product.

For more info :[Arm64 architecture in xcode 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1/22370158#22370158)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your target simulator from x86_64 to x86. The 4.4 SDK should work with all devices (32 and 64 bits), but only with the 32 bits version of the simulator.

PS: A fix for this is on the way. Source: I work at Chartboost