# Application Loader error, binary is invalid

Tags: ios, xcode

When i try to send my app to App Store, i'm getting this error:

The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seems to have been built whit Apple's linker.

i don't know where is the error in my app

Comment: Missing information: did you actually build with XCode? What version of XCode?

Comment: Check my answer in other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31611959/1698467 It could resolve your issue also.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
My solution :
Remove arm64 from Valid Architectures, the last IPA that I uploaded didn't have arm64 so I compared the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO

I used this command to get LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO

```
otool -arch all -Vl YOURAPP.app/YOURAPP | grep -A5 LC_ENCRYP
```

Result with ARM64:

```
    
      cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO
      cmdsize 20
    cryptoff  16384
    cryptsize 2375680
    cryptid   0
Load command 13
--
          cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO
      cmdsize 20
    cryptoff  16384
    cryptsize 2375680
    cryptid   0
Load command 13
--
          cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO_64
      cmdsize 24
    cryptoff  16384
    cryptsize 2801664
    cryptid   0
        pad   0
```

Result without ARM64

```
          cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO
      cmdsize 20
    cryptoff  16384
    cryptsize 2375680
    cryptid   0
Load command 13
--
          cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO
      cmdsize 20
    cryptoff  16384
    cryptsize 2375680
    cryptid   0
Load command 13
```

I hope this will help you, if someone know why remove ARM64 help to resolve this, the response interest me too.

Comment: I'm having this problem but with a phonegap build app. Is this something I can do with the ipa I get from them or if I extract the ipa and do something there? I ran your terminal command on the extracted guts and got this,
`cmdsize 20
cryptoff 16384
cryptsize 147456
cryptid 0
Load command 12`

Comment: Today it became a mass problem... After updating itunesconnect greatly changed the requirements to uploadable applications. I have tried to change Architectures to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) in project and all sub-projects (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1 ), but the problem was not fixed.