# This binary does not seem to have been built with Apples Linker

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, application-loader

I've built an app using phonegap build for ios and android. Both versions work great using their respective developer versions. The android app was sent off to google play smoothly and was quickly available on the android market. From there it is downloaded and installed without a hitch.
The fate of the ios version is not so great. When I upload the ipa (mmm, beer) phonegap build gives me using Application Loader I get the following error,

`ERROR ITMS-9000: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."`

I've reached out on phonegap build's community page but received no help.
I've reached out to the apple developer page and they told me to learn how to write native code.

I've checked, double checked, and recreated certificates and provisioning files. I'm sure they're for production. I am at a loss as to how to proceed. It seems I'm the only person to ever get this error from a phonegap build.

I saw this on stack overflow, [Application Loader error, binary is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936989/application-loader-error-binary-is-invalid), I did what it said but my results more or less matched what he said was the working one. You can seem my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on an old mac. I'd downloaded the latest application loader (2.9.1) to upload the build.phonegap ipa. While attempting to build the ipa myself i downloaded xcode 4.6.3 and it included application loader 2.8. Since it was different I thought I'd give it a shot using the exact ipa that had failed me so many times before. And it went through... I don't know what it was that made apple finally like my app but they do now and I'm not going to complain.

Answer (score 0):

I got his issue, when try to use `Pods` with minimum support version 8.0.

But my app's minimum support version was 7.0.

I changed min version to 8.0 and fix version in `Podspec`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

and run `pod install`

After this the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the problem was I had added one framework with drag and drop and when I deleted the framework and installed it through cocoapods the problem was gone