# Invalid binary, the binary is missing architectures[arm64]

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Today I cannot submit the binary to App Store, with the error "Invalid binary, the binary is missing architectures[arm64]".

But in "build settings"->"architectures", it does have arm64.

The previous version can be submitted successfully, and I haven't modified project settings.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have used "latest xcode" version 5.1.1 or higher to create build as well verify your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936989/application-loader-error-binary-is-invalid & http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/

Comment: Xcode version is 5.1.1(5B1008)

Comment: I have the same problem I've changed the Build Settings under Architectures I've added Stanndard architectures and added arm64 but the build cannot pass trough

Comment: I am facing Same Issue , can some one help

Comment: Tried it with Xcode 6.0 and Xcode 5.1.1 same effect.<br>

Have the Architectures set to "armv7 armv7s" and Valid Architectures also set to "armv7 armv7s"

Strang thing - even a last week successfully submitted version get the same error today (along with the fact that the version number is not increased). Had the same architectures settings in that successfully submitted version.

Is Apple accepting only Apps with support for arm64 as well from now on? Did I missed some announcements?

Comment: @Yasika i guess that link does not help. Jessie has explicitly removed / unset arm64 so there is no arm64 slice in the binary. That matches the settings but the uploader states an error.

Answer (score 3):

As TimT stated in this thread: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/244448, It is apparently a bug.
However, it's still not resolved...

*Not enough reputation to post image, please search "TimT" for his reply.*

**UPDATE:**

It has been fixed. "Yes, there was a fix recently applied to the server. Everyone should be able to submit 32-bit apps again." - by TimT in the same thread. I tried again and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

After a long period of trying and trying to fix this issue, I haven't got any solution, but to install the older version of Xcode 5.0.2 and submit the binary with that one.

Cheers :)

Comment: yes it will upload the binary successfully but note that the version will not be compatible with the new iOS 8 and new iPhones...

Comment: You can download a version of the Xcode 5.0.2 and install it but keep both versions of Xcode and change only the command tools when publishing an app..

Comment: But in itunes connect, it says "Submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later." >_<

Comment: yes it says that but you can submit your app, and it will not support 64 bit archi. and it wouldn't be supported on the new iOS and iPhones. if you try you can assure that the build submitted with Xcode 5.0.2 will appear with the version of the app to the build section under your app settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in the morning and apparently it was one of the 3rd party library/framework that it was missing architectures[arm64].

Answer (score 0):

Seems that app must support arm64 now.

In my situation, I used some third party Library which doesn't support arm64.

I deleted the Libraries, and it's OK now.

The Architectures setting looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Have you found any documentations from apple which state that they will no longer accept Apps with no arm64 architecture?

Comment: This is a false statement. I just submitted multiple new apps and app updates without selecting arm64 architecture for them and all my uploads went through without a problem

Comment: @Joachim There is no official documentation. After I delete the Library that doesn't support arm64, everything is ok now. Of course, with some functions removed, such as sso login with some sns sites.

Comment: @SamBudda Do you have third party library in your project?