# Running arm64-incompatible app from XCode in debug mode on an arm64 device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode5, arm64

I'm maintaining an iPad app that uses a closed source library that is currently not compiled for arm64. As a result, I can't run the app directly from XCode on an iPad Air.

Is there a way to get XCode to run it as a 32bit app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arm64 architecture in xcode 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1)

Comment: @auselen possibly, although my question deals specifically with running it on a device and not the simulator.