# "Missing required architecture arm64 in file..."Xcode 6 beta when running in ios 7 device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Im currently making a project in swift and its going allright..

But when I run my app on my device (iPhone 5s -iOS 7.1), XCode returns me the following error

```
ld: in '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib', missing required architecture arm64
in file /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib (2 slices) for architecture arm64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried removing derived data but it didn't work and I couldn't find any other answers to that question.

**EDIT:** Running on simulator with iOS 7 (both 32bit and 64bit sims) works flawlessly.

Comment: did you add `arm64` Achitectures and ValiAchitectures?

Comment: i didn't even touch any of that. It says that Architectures contains armv7 and arm64 and ValidArch contains arm64 armv7 and armv7s

Comment: Have you tried setting all architectures for the debug and release settings in build settings?

Comment: They're all the same.

Comment: Are you using a static library? or any external libraries?

Comment: if you are using a external library then u need to get library that supports `arm64` architecture . Else if you are using static library ..even there u need to set `arm64` for that library to build.

Comment: Im using cocoapods for dependencies. As far as i know all my libraries support it and I think that if it was an error on those pods it would specify. And by the way the library being pointed by the error is: '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib'

Answer (score 1):

[image: Do u have this architecture type with you under architectures]

Do u have this architecture type with you under architectures.Sry had to add image so created a post .

Also did u try setting Build Active architectore only to NO .

Is the arm64 architecture required in ur project?... if u dont need it please check this SO link to edit the architectures.[Click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1)

Comment: On Architectures i have only armv7 and arm64.
Changed Build Active Achitecture to NO and after cleaning Derived Data it changed the error to: 

`ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Then I changed Pods project Build Active Achitecture also to NO and the error became the initial one again.

Comment: if no u can remove the architecture using the link above and  also u can remove from cocoapods following this link. http://cameronspickert.com/2014/01/20/remove-the-arm64-architecture-from-cocoapods-targets.html

Comment: I removed from cocoapods and from my main project and the error presented is this:

`ld: in '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib', missing required architecture armv7 in file /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib (2 slices) for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` 

As far as i know i do not require arm64

Comment: sos did u set architectures to arm7 armv7

Comment: The architectures are the default ones. I did what the example you gave me showed and didn't work. Currently my Architecture is displaying: Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64) - &(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Comment: i just wanted to let u know how to change...... make the standard architectures to arm7 armv7