# iOS Wikitude SDK build error "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, build-error, wikitude

I'm trying to make an app with Wikitude, I followed all the steps on the Wikitude init page for the SDK setup in iOS (http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios) and when I try to build the project, I get exactly 8 build errors

[image]

[image]

I Googled this, but nothing actual came up, all from 2014 and not exactly my problem too.

I tried the following solutions, but nothing worked for me:
   - [Arm64 architecture in xcode 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323039/arm64-architecture-in-xcode-5-1)
   - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add CoreMedia to the list of frameworks.

Usually you can determine which framework is missing by the starting letters and function name of the missing symbols.  _CM + VideoFormat -> CoreMotion.